# export to excel 2016 from sharepoint 2013 custom list in windows 10 using IE 11

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, export

I have windows 10 os on my machine and I am trying to export sharepoint 2013 custom list in excel 2016 using IE 11 but it shows me below error:

**"cannot connect to the server at this time.Changes to your data cannot be saved"**

Can any one suggest me which actions should I take to resolve this.

Comment: I have the same setup and can confirm it is possible.  There is no incompatibility in this setup.

Answer (score 1):

This issue generally encountered with `Windows 7`, `Office 2016` and `SharePoint 2013`.

But it should be working with `windows 10` . so Make sure that you don't have old office versions beside office 2016. if you have try to remove old versions.

Also, the following steps may be helpful to overcome this issue

- Go to internet option.
- Advanced Settings.
- below Security.
- Uncheck `Check for publisher's certificate revocation`.

Check also

- [SharePoint 2013 Compatibility with Office 2016](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/03a3a4d1-076f-4f06-9a4f-9a6ef72cde3b?category=sharepointadmin)
- [The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/02/the-server-was-unable-to-save-the-form-at-this-time-please-try-again-in-sharepoint-2013/)